# How to perform arithmetic on automator variables

Tags: applescript, automator

I'd like to be able to divide the value of a variable in Automator by 2, before being passed to the next step. I imagine it can be done with 'run applescript' but can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. If you have a variable with a number in it, you can:

1. Get Value of Variable
2. Run AppleScript

with the AppleScript something like:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set halfInput to input / 2

    return halfInput
end run
```

I’ve attached a screenshot of this, so you can see how it works.

[image: Automator, using AppleScript to halve a numeric variable.]

Note that depending on where the variable is set, it might be a list, in which case you’ll need to get the appropriate item from the list. For example, passing the result of a shell script to a variable will mean that the value is in a list, and the AppleScript will need to get the “first item of input” in order to treat that value as a number. Here’s an example:

[image: Passing value from shell script to variable and then to AppleScript.]